# Close button like facebook wall or youtube

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm a huge newb when it comes to javascript/jQuery/Ajax.  I'm looking to learn how to add a close button to content on my site similar to facebook's wall or youtube's experimental homepage.

Where is the starting point to do this?  jQuery UI?  Any other packaged solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to have a list of links to the function that you want to execute and hide them.

Then, when you click on the close button, it makes that list appear.

Here's a simple example

http://www.jsfiddle.net/9scYR/

Comment: I'm looking for it to update a mysql database and only show on hover. Not just show/hide elements.

Comment: Then you need a server-side language. And the idea is the same. The links point to functions that do what you want. This is just the html  + css + js idea behind the facebook like close button like you asked.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to do it all with css and html/php.  I thought it would be more complicated.  I guess if I wanted to give it more fluid motion I'd need javascript to animate the content.